# How pointer variable works, without initialising it in the code in TurboC++?

Tags: c, pointers, turbo-c

I am new to C. I was just interested in making a program which takes two integer input from the user and add it but the condition is that i have to use only one variable. I came up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int *a;
scanf("%d%d",a,(a+1));
printf("\nSum=%d",*a+*(a+1));
return 0;
}
```

`scanf()` function takes an valid address as an argument and i am passing the value in `a`(which is not initialised yet). So, how this code worked in Turbo C++?

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior. That can do anything, it doesn't have to cause an obvious error.

Comment: When code breaks the rules "Pointer is not initialised" and `scanf("%d%d",a,(a+1));`, the compilers do not need to follow any rules either.

Comment: @chux Then, where is the numbers are stored. It must be stored in a valid location. I want to know the location where it is saved. `a` doesn't contain any valid address.

Comment: Please stop doing crazy things and then asking SO users to explain the crazy.  We can't explain UB, by definition.  We can have no idea what is happening on your system.

Comment: @Apy Yes sir, you are absolutely correct. I experimented with it and it gave me wrong answers after sometime. But i want to know when it gave me the correct answer, the value in the `a` was a valid location(within the scope of the program)?

Comment: When you got the correct answer the adjacent cell of a is still unused by OS. So you were able to access it without error. But this is a malpractice as with this you can damage variables used by other programs.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit sir their is nothing wrong in doing experiments with codes. Even, Mark Zuckerberg done crazy things due to which you are using Facebook today.

Comment: I'm downvoting this because it's just not constructive. Bad code is bad code. Undefined is undefined. Questions of this nature are a total waste of time.

Comment: @Apy sir but `scanf()` function takes the address of the location in which the numbers will be stored. Instead of address, I have given the value of `a`. Yes, `a` is a pointer variable which stores an address of any other location. But, `a` is not initialised. So, where will the first number will be stored?

Comment: a is doing fine. a+1 is undefined.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley i just wanted to know the nature of pointers through this. I am not saying the code is correct.

Comment: @varunzxzx Think like this. You have key to your house(a) and your next house(a+1). Now, if there's no one in the next house, it's fine (your situation). But if your neighbors are there, they will call 100! Bam! GCC caught you.

Comment: @Apy means `a` will contain a valid location?

Comment: yes, why not? a is defined in your program! so a is valid.

Comment: but `a` is blank, it must contain some garbage value. In the `scanf()` function i have used `a` instead of `&a`. Which means  i am passing the value stored in `a` as an address to `scanf()` function. So, how it is using the garbage value as a location?

Comment: No! We always pass the address of the variable in `scanf`. In `scanf("%d",&a)` we pass address of a. When you are using `scanf("%d",a)` you basically pass the address of `a` as `a` is a pointer and just `a` means the address of `a`. To pass value stored in a pointer(maybe garbage when uninitialized) you need to use `*a`. So, what you demands can be fulfilled by `scanf("%d",*a)` which is illegal to use.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you very much sir. Now, i understood it.

Comment: @varunzxzx. No problem! :)

Comment: No, a value [must be stored in a valid location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297865/how-pointer-variable-works-without-initialising-it-in-the-code-in-turboc?noredirect=1#comment73661416_43297865) is not true.   C is  not specified to work that way.  The behavior is undefined.  Anything may happen.

Comment: [`a` is blank, it must contain some garbage value.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297865/how-pointer-variable-works-without-initialising-it-in-the-code-in-turboc?noredirect=1#comment73662333_43297865) is not specified to be true in C.  `a` is uninitialized when first used in `scanf("%d%d",a,(a+1));`.  The value in `a` is not specified to be garbage. its value is not relevant.  Attempting to use it before initialization/assignment is undefined behavior.  Anything may happen.

Comment: 'sir their is nothing wrong in doing experiments with codes' - indeed.  You are 100% correct.  Please feel free to investigate the UB on your system.  I'm not stopping you.  What I'm saying is that other users on other systems cannot assist you with your very own in-house, private UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access an area that is not within the scope of the program. Luckily TCC gave it, but I believe if you go on experimenting, results will be undefined.

You can do something like this to solve your problem of adding using 1 variable.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a); //scan the first number
    getchar();
    a += getchar()-'0'; // get the second number (restricted to 0-9)
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow, nice one. thnx sir